# resizing react app text goes under navbar and sidenav

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a react app I created just for fun.  I have a topnav using react-bootstrap and a sidenav I cobbled together.  Both work and my navbar is reactive in that it switches to habburger menu as the page size shrinks that is all fine.

My issue is text on the display page goes under my 2 navbars as the page shrinks.  Is there anyway I can have the page content always stay outside of the navbars.

[image: Here is the page on mobile]

The code in my app.js is as such

```
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>
        <NavigationBar />
        <Jumbotron />
        <Sidebar />
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/regions" exact component={Regions} />
            <Route path="/regions/:id" component={ItemDetail} />
            <Route path="/races" exact component={Races} />
            <Route path="/races/desc" exact component={Desc} />
            <Route path="/races/dwarves" exact component={Dwarves} />
            <Route path="/wallbreak" component={Wallbreak} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </Layout>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with some CSS in both my index.csss and my sidenav.css

added
padding-left: 60px:
padding-top: 40px;